# Update Host file to update last entry based on Hostname

Tags: windows, powershell, hostname, hosts

For some reason, one of our customers has a lot of problems connecting to our ftp, main reason being that he cant resolve our hostname (via IP no problem)

I've been looking around and found this code to add a line to the bottom of my host file (but its not working, just outputs the host file in its entirety)

Can someone explain how I can change this? It is fetching the IP perfectly, just need to either delete the non commented lines on host file or delete the last IP

```
$targethost="HOSTNAME"
$dnsserver="8.8.8.8"
$pattern = '^*' + $targethost + '.*$'
$file = "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
$ip = Resolve-DnsName -Name $targethost -Type A -DnsOnly -Server $dnsserver
$hosts = Get-Content -Path $file

$hosts = $hosts | Foreach {
  if ($_ -match $pattern) 
  {
      $ip.IpAddress + "   HOSTNAME "
  } 
  else 
  {
    # Keep current line
    $_
  }
}

#Uncomment this line to just view the output, no harm is done to the hosts file.
$hosts


# Uncomment this line to actually write the hosts file. Elevated privileges required.
#$hosts | Out-File $file -enc ASCII
```

Comment: `# Uncomment this line to actually write the hosts file. Elevated privileges required.` take the `#` at the very bottom of the file out.

Comment: What he said^^.

Comment: Obviously i tried that, still doesn't pump into the file OR shows it in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$hosts | Out-File -Encoding Ascii -append $file
```

or

```
$hosts | Add-Content $file #(ASCII by default)
```

Answer (score 0):

A janky one, but it works

```
Clear-Content c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Set-Content -Path c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value "Hello, World"
$targethost="HOSTNAME"
$dnsserver="8.8.8.8"
$pattern = '^*' + $targethost + '.*$'
$file = "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
$ip = Resolve-DnsName -Name $targethost -Type A -DnsOnly -Server $dnsserver
$hosts = Get-Content -Path $file

$hosts = $hosts | Foreach {
  if ($_ -match $pattern) 
  {
      # Keep current line
    $_

  } 
  else 
  {
   $ip.IpAddress + "   HOSTNAME "
  }
}

#Uncomment this line to just view the output, no harm is done to the hosts file.
$hosts


# Uncomment this line to actually write the hosts file. Elevated privileges required.
$hosts | Out-File $file -enc ASCII
```